# Cannot login to Django admin

Tags: django, authentication, admin, development-environment

My admin login in development stopped working suddenly. It used to be working fine for almost a year. I am able to see the login page and type the superuser credentials. When I click on the login button, nothing happens. The admin log also does not show anything. I have tried changing the port number and ran the server.
I even created a new project and new database and tried running the simple admin page, no luck. I tried running the admin for other projects in development, still nothing happens on clicking the login button.
My settings does have:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'),
)
```

Another thing that I noticed was I do not get a new row in the django_session table even after I login with the correct superuser credentials

Comment: It looked like something was wrong with my Firefox. I removed the .mozilla folder and it worked fine

Comment: Where is this .mozilla folder? I'm running into the same problem now.

Comment: I made a copy of my .mozilla folder and deleted the existing .mozilla. It maybe a little hacky, but it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to clear your localhost cookies and try with another browser.
I've issues with chrome v28 that I don't have in firefox v22.
Let me know if it helps.
Regards.

-- EDIT --

Try to put this line in your settings.py. It solved for me.

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None

Comment: Thank you Reichert. I tried that and it did not help. It is the same problem with Firefox as well. This is the same problem for 40+ users using the system

Answer (score 0):

Opening the application in chrome's `incognito mode` resolved this issue for me.